# data[ ] in jsonp - what it means?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, jsonp, wikipedia-api

I am making an API request to Wikipedia, and everything seems to work but I can't figure out the meaning for the few lines of code, precisely

```
var articleTitles = data[1];
var articleUrls = data[3];
```

I have no idea what do index data[1] and data[3] mean and how do I figure out them on my own. This is from the Udacity tutorial but this was not clarified in detail, I only know it has something to do with the response...

```
var wikiUrl = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=' + cityStr + '&format=json';

    var wikiRequestTimeout = setTimeout(function () {
        $wikiElem.text("Failed to get Wikipedia resources");
    }, 5000);

    $.ajax({
        url: wikiUrl,
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    }).success(function(data) {
        var articleTitles = data[1];
        var articleUrls = data[3];

        $.each(articleTitles, function(i, title) {
            $wikiElem.append('<li><a href="' + articleUrls[i] + '">' + title + '</a></li>');
        });
    /*  .error is not built into jsonp
*/
        clearTimeout(wikiRequestTimeout); // clear timeout will stop timeout from happening
    });

return false;
```

Comment: I would log the object in console to see how the data is actually structured.

Answer (score 0):

`data` is an object you can perceive it as an array (like) structure. It contains other arrays/objects inside of it, and to answer the question `data[0]` is the first of those child arrays and `data[3]` is the 4th one (it is a 0 based notation).
You can check this out - http://www.w3schools.com/json/json_syntax.asp